# delay in setting 'after' function in python tkinter

Tags: python, events, tkinter

I'm writing a short application in python using tkinter. Everything works except for an unexpected pause - it should be generating an event twice a second, but frequently it will pause for 5 or 6 seconds between signals. I've put print statements to find where the delay is, and found it is the following statement:

> self.frame.after(ms, self.tick_handler)

ms is 500 so this should send the event at around .5 seconds. Usually it does, but frequently it hangs for as much as 5 or 6 seconds before tick_handler() gets the signal. The program is pretty simple, with a single worker thread receiving all input from a single queue, events coming from a single tkinter frame. The `after()` statement is in the worker thread. I've tried shutting off gc (`gc.disable()`) but that makes no difference. There is minimal activity outside this on my computer.

If I send other input during the pause using mouse or keys it is handled immediately, so the worker thread is not blocked. It looks as if the signal request is received but not fired for some time. I know I can't expect real time performance so .6 seconds wouldn't be noteworthy, but 6.0 seconds?

This is the first time I've worked with tkinter. Is there something I am missing about event handling?

Answer (score 0):

I Think You Did Not Include `tkinter.mainloop()` At The End

PS: I'm Not Sure...

Comment: Sorry, that isn't it, the code does run properly, just with the delay. I know it would have been better if I could have made a short example and included a full program, but short test programs I tried didn't have the problem.

Comment: Thanks, but it's a little long to include, I'm still seeing the behavior but after some unrelated changes it is a little better (3-4 seconds rather than 5-6). The program (multiboard tetris) is just for my own instruction. If this turned out to be a known issue I'd like to know, otherwise I'll just chalk it up to experience and move on.

Comment: Sometimes it happens with me too...  I think calling it through a widget ```tkinter.Button["command"]``` would help

Comment: Interesting. I'll see if I can call from within a button, though currently the logic has it done in the worker thread. I've found the severity seems to change with organization. Also, when I run with multiple boards (worker threads), each setting the after delay, it works much BETTER. Running 2 threads for 3 minutes I saw only 2 delays of 3 seconds, running a single board would have 10 times that many.

Answer (score 0):

When using the `after`  method in tkinter, instead of doing `root.after(function_name,time_delayed)` do `root.after(function_name(),time_delayed)`  as this worked for me and the delay disappeared.

Comment: I have some concerns about this.  Doing `function_name()` instead of `function_name` will mean the method is invoked immediately rather than after the frame is completed.  It may have masked the issue rather than resolved it.